# R pick time range

Tags: r

So I would like to get a subset of all the data after a certain time. for example here's a table I have

```
[what i have][1]
```

I would like all the data after,and including,  2016-11-01 08:08:00

So that it looks like this

```
  [what i want][1]
```

Basically I have a dataframe of all the days of the month,time sorted, and would like to get all the data after a certain time, in this case all times after 4pm.

And then I would like to search in the subset by day, so search for 11-01, then 11-02,11-03 and such

I used

```
as.POSIXct(month$stopdate, format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S%p")
```

to format the time.

Thank you

edited:replaced data set text with images because of how bad/hard it is to type it in here

Comment: Assuming your data frame is called `df`, you can do: `df[df$stopdate >= as.POSIXct("2016-11-01 04:00:00"), ]`. To search for rows that are in specific dates, for example: df[as.Date(df$stopdate) %in% seq(as.Date("2016-11-01"), as.Date("2016-11-03"), by="day"), ]`.

Comment: how can i do it where it will do it for the whole month, basically give all the data when stopdate time is after 04:00:00 so like 11/1 after 4, 11/2 after 4, 11/3 after 4 and such

Comment: I cannot see any dataset.